# Firebase get current value of an entry

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

in my app there is a score entry which should count every vote of the user. So if the user votes up the value of `score` increases about one.

I know how to set the new value but I'm unable to get the current entry.

So with this I can log the actual score:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("test").orderByChild("name");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        long score = ds.child("score").getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Score: " + score);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

But how I can use a value of a certain entry?

With this I'm getting an error

```
@Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.child(name.getName()).exists()) {
            up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    names.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            score = dataSnapshot.child("Test").child("Name").getValue(long.class);
                            score += 1;
                            final Name name = new Name(txtName.getText().toString(), score);
                            try {
                                names.child(name.getName()).setValue(name);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
              at user.prof.name.Activities.Result$1$1$1.onDataChange(Result.java:80)
              at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
              at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
              at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6589)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Do you have any idea?

Edit:

Here is the structure:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- test
       |
       --- Name1
       |     |
       |     --- name: "Name1"
       |     |
       |     --- score: 0
       |
       --- Name2
             |
             --- name: "Name2"
             |
             --- score: 15
```

Comment: Would you add the firebase database structure? It seems like long returns null. Perhaps the query has an issue or something? However, `Test` is using uppercase but in the above codes it was lowercase. Anyways, can't help without checking the structure..

Comment: I've updated the post. Thank you. Should the `Test` be upper or lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your structure, you can use something like this for changing the first `Name1` (for example):

```
score = dataSnapshot.child("test").child("Name1").child("score").getValue();
```

Then set your data by `setValue()`.

**Note** that this would only work if your query hasn't any issues and it starts by getting the reference first.

**Update:** You might need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to avoid looping.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test"); 
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                score = dataSnapshot.child("Name1").child("score").getValue();

                ...
                // and the rest
```

Comment: Anytime, glad to help. Using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will solve that issue.

Comment: You saved my day with this simple method. Again, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You've to make the node name exactly the same, it should be `test` and how I see  is that, you've not described your `names` reference in the attached code. You should try it like this:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test").child("Name1");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            score = dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue(long.class);
                            score += 1;
                            final Name name = new Name(txtName.getText().toString(), score);
                            try {
                                names.child(name.getName()).setValue(name);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It is increasing, but it increase till invinity. How can I avoid that? With a for-loop?

Comment: You can add a statement like `if` with `score` being greater than a certain point to break from the method.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can mark it as correct, I'd appreciate that. Cheers :)

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm too stupid for that simple method. Here is my thought: `score--;
 if(score == dataSnapshot.child("count").getValue(long.class)-1) {           
 //than add to database }                                                                              else { finish();`                                                                                               But it starts again at 0 and counts again to infinity. What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Comment: @Hansi Check my answer about the infinite loop.

Comment: Wow, that was too simple. Thank you very much Sir @Mohsen and Sir Pradyuman Dixit

Comment: Oh, sorry for late reply, couldn't see it there. Glad your problem is solve, Cheers :)